# Unable to locate package ros-groovy-openni2-launch

Tags: ros, kinect, xtion, openni2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

i'm trying to install and use my Xtion camera with Ubuntu 12.04 ROS Groovy.  This is a fresh install.
I **should** be install the openni2 package using
`sudo apt-get install -f ros-groovy-openni2-launch` ... right?
But, I'm getting this message

`Reading package lists... Done Building dependency tree        Reading state information... Done   E: Unable to locate package ros-groovy-openni2-launch enter code here`

I've attempted installing following the directions here: http://answers.ros.org/question/190377/how-to-setup-xtion-pro-live-ubuntu-1404-openni12/ by replacing 'hydra' with 'groovy'. No luck.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/225886/unable-to-locate-package-ros-groovy-openni2-launch/) by [joe.s](https://answers.ros.org/users/3410/joe.s/) on ROS Answers with karma: 162 on 2016-02-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> I **should** be install the openni2 package using `sudo apt-get install -f ros-groovy-openni2-launch` ... right?

No, as according to [debbuild/groovy.html?q=openni](http://www.ros.org/debbuild/groovy.html?q=openni), that particular package was never released into Groovy. Only the `openni2_camera` package was (see the `deb` on `packages.ros.org` [here](http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/pool/main/r/ros-groovy-openni2-camera/) fi). The [wiki page](http://wiki.ros.org/openni2_launch) also shows this: notice the `Released`, `Continuous integration` and `Documented` badges on the Hydro, Indigo and Jade pages, but only the `Documented` one on the Groovy page.

As to options: you could try to see whether you can build the package from source in a Groovy catkin workspace. Probably best to checkout the [groovy-devel](https://github.com/ros-drivers/openni2_launch/tree/groovy-devel) branch. It's just a set of launch files, so it could work.

Alternatively, try to build all `openni2` packages from source, using the `hydro-devel` branch. That will probably be a bit more involved, as things might have changed between Groovy and Hydro in an incompatible way.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2016-02-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joe.s](https://answers.ros.org/users/3410/joe.s/) on 2016-02-05**:
Ok.
What's not so fun is that I'm also having trouble with the Asus Xtion and openni2 in Hydro.  I'm getting this error: `[ERROR] [140934478.275581907]: Unsupported color video mode - Resolution: 640x480 30Hz Format:RGB888` ...
basically what this guy is seeing: answers.ros.org/question/191498/

**Comment by [joe.s](https://answers.ros.org/users/3410/joe.s/) on 2016-02-05**:
But, since I don't want to upgrade to Indigo at this time... I'm going to keep looking (and post another thread)

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-02-05**:
I'm afraid I can't help you with the Xtion issue. Opening a new question would seem to be a good idea, yes.

**Comment by [joe.s](https://answers.ros.org/users/3410/joe.s/) on 2016-02-05**:
thanks. on its way now.